# Variables/variations increase in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, woocommerce, product-variations

I have increased the number of allowed variables within WooCommerce from the default 30 to 50 using this in my `functions.php`.

But I get an error saying:

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in
>   /.../wp-includes/load.php on line 63.

It still saves the variation and the product, but I think somehow there is something missing from this function?

Can anyone help identify it?

```
function woo_custom_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) {
return 50;
}       
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'woo_custom_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: This hook is working just perfectly as it is (and your code too, without errors), I have test it. So your problem is coming from another source as a plugin, the theme or your server configuration and settings, and is not possible with the information you are providing to find out which source is responsible. You have not increase the number of variables, but the number of displayed variations for an attribute in front end… (see below)

Comment: [**ABOUT THIS HOOK:**](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/improving-the-variations-interface-in-2-4/) On front end, WooCommerce display by default **20** variations *(Not 30)* **for an attribute, once page is loaded**. If there is **more than 20 variations for an attribute**, the others variations will be ***displayed progressively via ajax**. So the purpose of this hook (your code) is to allow displaying at start (once page is loaded) more than 20 variations for 1 attribute: If you have a product that have 75 variations for 1 attribute, you can set a value of 75 to be returned…